Do male Christians who wear ear rings in violation of God's commandment?
According to mainstream Christians, is it lawful for a born-again male Christian to wear an ear ring? The Bible seems to have warned against this practice through a letter Paul wrote to the church in Corinth.
1 Corinthians 6:9 (KJV)

Know ye not that the unrighteous shall not inherit the kingdom of God? Be not deceived: neither fornicators, nor idolaters, nor adulterers, nor effeminate, nor abusers of themselves with mankind

It seems as if this is a warning to all male Christians to avoid effeminate habits which includes wearing ear rings and other behaviors associated with women, is that enough for male Christians who behave that way?

The wearing of gold items is forbidden by Paul but I cannot see that a man wearing an earring can be accused of being 'effeminate'. Working, as I do, in Security, I meet lots of men wearing earrings and they don't seem effeminate to me. Quite the opposite ! But they do not profess Christ and I would not expect a serious and solemn Christian man to be fussy about his appearance, myself.

@NigelJ, According to Merriam-Webster, effeminate is an adjective that means having feminine qualities that are not typically associated with men

Indeed. 'Qualities' does not convey superficial accoutrements. Which are ambiguous in their purpose.

@NigelJ, well the King James version condemns that behavior because ear rings have been traditionally associated with women or people of the female gender

I think you are struggling to prove your point, myself. I think I shall leave you to it and comment no further. Regards. (P.S. I do not wear earrings, myself.)

Why do you consider it effeminate to wear ear rings? Men have worn ear rings in loads of cultures through history.

Here is a good translation of the word translated effeminate in the KJV:  morally weak and lacking self-control and inner strength.

@curiousdannii, the body is the temple of the Holy Spirit, it needs to be maintained in the manner proposed by Christ as the first born from the dead, ear rings on a man's body defiles that image of a born again Christian

So are you against all piercings then? Women wearing earrings are also defiling the image of a born again Christian?

I’m voting to close this question because its asking if X is a sin, which is off topic

@depperm says "because its asking if X is a sin".  Actually it isn't. It's assuming that X is a sin. In fact the idea of earrings being effeminate is a relatively recent attitude. Pirates for instance weren't noted for their effeminate characteristics Why Did Pirates Wear Earrings?. It's the incorrect basic assumption of this question that makes it worth closing.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany says "ear rings have been traditionally associated with women or people of the female gender". That claim needs to be substantiated to make this a suitable question. And the tradition needs to from biblical society.

@curiousdannii, I don't trust a tattooed Christian and a male Christian with an earring, it means you have not surrendered yourself completely to Christ and still have a worldly attachment. Deuteronomy warns against marking our bodies, an earring is a pattern of this world that scripture commands us not to conform to the patterns of this world

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking if X is a sin, which is off topic

Note that many believe 1 Corinthians 6:9 is speaking of homosexual acts. That's not to say that men behaving in a manner unbecoming of males is okay, but the specific passage cited is perhaps not the most relevant to that point. (Also, as repeatedly noted, cultural norms are not irrelevant, nor is one's intent in any particular action irrelevant.)

Do male Christians who wear ear rings in violation of God's commandment?
The short answer is no.

But each woman shall ask of her neighbor, and any woman who lives in her house, for silver and gold jewelry, and for clothing. You shall put them on your sons and on your daughters. So you shall plunder the Egyptians.” - Exodus 3:22 (ESV)

Many other texts in Sacred Scripture exist on this subject matter.
Men wearing earrings is not a sign of being effeminate, as history shows us that pirates actually wore earrings...

Your right pirates, and that term implies they are thieves. Born again Christians is different

@SoFewAgainstSoMany are you accusing Jews who followed a divine commandment of being thieves?

@AviAvraham, the term pirate is associated with someone who gets access to something through the back door. You cannot use the case of a pirate as an analogy because they are already worldly people, God created Adam and Eve without a mark and those metals

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, the point isn't that pirates are good people, it's that pirates aren't associated with being effeminate. The original question is meaningless unless it can substantiate the claim: "effeminate habits … includes wearing ear rings".

Earrings are a pattern of this world and scripture is explicitly against all born again Christians conforming to the patterns of this world, instead they should experience a renewing of the mind through the gospel of the Lord Jesus Christ.
Romans 12:2 (NIV)

Do not conform to the pattern of this world, but be transformed by the renewing of your mind. Then you will be able to test and approve what God's.
.

I have tested it and discovered that it is not from God because God created Adam and Eve without any metal or decoration on their bodies, they were perfect and good. Neither were they created with markings or tattoos, everything God did is perfect, he created us perfect in his own image without any decorations.

So everyone should all wear identical drab clothing? There are certainly denominations that believe the same, but it is hardly the view of "mainstream Christians", which is what the question asks about.

@RayButterworth, Jesus didn't come to do away with the law of Moses but to strengthen it

@RayButterworth, would you accept a pastor who preaches the word of God to you while putting earrings on?

What I would do is irrelevant. Questions and answers on this site are supposed to be objective and not personal.

"Earrings are a pattern of this world" — No, unless the Bible condemns them, they are simply a type of jewelry worn by various people in various cultures. There is nothing inherently effeminate about them.
¶　According to Jeremy Camp (wearing earrings)
in this Facebook Video,
earrings were normal, not effeminate, for him:
"Some side of the community wasn't accepting the tattoos and earrings.
For me it was just natural.
…
It was weird for me to realize that there was a side of people that were totally condemning that.".

Perhaps a visit to Scotland and a long discussion about kilts as a sign of effeminacy would help.

Your own question asks "According to mainstream Christians". As you have not provided any evidence that this is what mainstream Christians think, this is not a valid answer.

Wearing clothes is also a "pattern of this world" which was not practiced by Adam and Eve before the fall. Are you saying Christians should refuse to wear clothes?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Jesus came to fulfil the law, not strengthen it.

@DJclayworth God clothed them with skins made from a lamb after the light of God which was their original cloth was removed due to sin.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Their original cloth???? Which Bible are you reading?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany says "God clothed them with skins made from a lamb" — What is a citation for where this knowledge comes from?

@DJClayworth, Bible mysteries are exposed in other books, the state of Adam and Eve before their fall can be debunked using the New Testament, now Saint John said the clothes of Jesus were there after he rose from the dead, does that imply Jesus is without clothes? No but rather a light or some form of glory covers the body of Jesus, which is the glory Jesus came to restore to humanity after they lost it through sin.
